# emu8086 - How do i terminate a program according to a condition

Tags: assembly, emulation, emu8086

i just want to ask how do i terminate or close the program after it meets a condition. im near to finishing this case study.. thanks for answering :]

like:

```
cmp byte ptr [sel3_1+2], 'a'
je stop

stop:
*code here*
```

or something that coded to stop under the condition

Comment: There's a DOS system call (`int 21h`) that exits your program.  Run it when you want that to happen.  It's no different from running any other system call conditionally, except that it never returns.

Answer (score 4):

Call INT 21h with service 4CH - exit with a return code,  put the return code in AL.

So,

```
MOV AH, 4CH
MOV AL, 01 ;your return code.
INT 21H
```

Or to exit without a return code, use service 0...

```
MOV AH, 0
INT 21H
```

Comment: Note that you can sacrifice human-readability for smaller code size by using `mov ax , 4C01H` to load both halves of the register with one instruction.  Also, I'd suggest using valid comments (`;`) to explain stuff in your example code.

Comment: Actually DOS will exit with a _return code = 0_ when you use `mov ah,0` `int 21h`. Additionally there's the even shorter way to exit a program just writing `int 20h`.